# How to make a chart in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

How to make a chart in ASP.NET so that I can display data from database using the chart. Any body can explain me? Thank you.

Comment: You have to use canvas or svg or google chart api. I suggest you to go with Google's chart api.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{ 
var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery"); 
var dbdata = db.Query("SELECT Name, Price FROM Product"); 
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400) 
   .AddTitle("Product Sales") 
   .DataBindTable(dataSource: dbdata, xField: "Name")
   .Write();
}
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_chart.asp)